# Getting rockets to display next to each other

Tags: java

Yes this is a homework question. However, I don't think it is a problem to use stack exchange to solve homework problems. This is what real programmers do, don't they.

I have this program that prints two rocket ships to the console. The rockets are stacked vertically. I would like them to appear side-by-side. Is there a way to do this without changing all my static methods?

```
public class TwoRockets {

    public static void main (String[] args) {       
        appearrocket();
        appearrocket();     
    }

    public static void appearrocket() {         
        cone();
        box();
        label();
        box();
        cone();
    }       

    public static void box() {          
        System.out.println("+------+");
        System.out.println("|      |");
        System.out.println("|      |");
        System.out.println("+------+");         
    }

    public static void cone() {         
        System.out.println("   /\\");
        System.out.println("  /  \\");
        System.out.println(" /    \\");
    }

    public static void label() {            
        System.out.println("| VIVA |");
        System.out.println("|MEXICO|");
    }
}
```

Comment: No. You will have to change your static methods. Not directly printing to System.out, but assembling stuff in memory so that it can be rearranged in columns could be one approach. Using object instances instead of static methods will help with that, too (you will have two rockets after all).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to modify the static methods.
By using concatenation operator you can achieve two rockets side by side.
comment out one //appearrocket();

```
package com.stackover.ex;


public class TwoRockets {

    public static void main (String[] args) {

        appearrocket();     
        //appearrocket();

    }



    public static void appearrocket() {

        cone();
        box();
        label();
        box();
        cone();     
    }



    public static void box() {

        System.out.println("+------+\t"+"+------+");
        System.out.println("|      |\t"+"|      |");
        System.out.println("|      |\t"+"|      |");
        System.out.println("+------+\t"+"+------+");

    }

    public static void cone() {

        System.out.println("   /\\\t\t"+"   /\\");
        System.out.println("  /  \\\t\t"+"  /  \\");
        System.out.println(" /    \\\t\t"+" /    \\");      
    }

    public static void label() {

        System.out.println("| VIVA |\t"+"| VIVA |");
        System.out.println("|MEXICO|\t"+"|MEXICO|");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A generic edition which can handle any number of side-by-side rockets just by changing the value of the variable copies:

```
public class TwoRockets {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    final int copies = 3;
    printCap(copies);
    printBox(copies);
    printUS(copies);
    printBox(copies);
    printCap(copies);
}

public static void printCap(int times) {
for (int i = 0; i < times; i++) {
    System.out.print("   /\\   ");
    System.out.print("\t");
}

System.out.println();

for (int i = 0; i < times; i++) {
    System.out.print("  /  \\  ");
    System.out.print("\t");
}

System.out.println();

}

private static void printBox(int times) {
for (int i = 0; i < times; i++) {
    System.out.print("+------+");
    System.out.print("\t");
}
System.out.println();

for (int i = 0; i < times; i++) {
    System.out.print("|      |");
    System.out.print("\t");
}
System.out.println();

for (int i = 0; i < times; i++) {
    System.out.print("|      |");
    System.out.print("\t");
}
System.out.println();

for (int i = 0; i < times; i++) {
    System.out.print("+------+");
    System.out.print("\t");
}

System.out.println();

}

private static void printUS(int times) {
for (int i = 0; i < times; i++) {
    System.out.print("|United|");
    System.out.print("\t");
}
System.out.println();

for (int i = 0; i < times; i++) {
    System.out.print("|States|");
    System.out.print("\t");
}
System.out.println();

}
```

}